# Why is Keynote using 10GB of disk space and how do I fix this?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, spaces, keynote

I'm running out of disk space notice Keynote is using 10GB of disk space. Why is this and how do I reclaim the space? I use Keynote once a week for a small presentation that I edit each week. Thanks

I’m using the latest version of MacOS and keynote which is Ventura and the latest keynote from the App Store.

[image: Disk Space Screenshot]

Comment: This screen sometimes includes the files generated by the app, not just the app itself. Tools like DaisyDisk will give you a clearer image of where space is being used.

Comment: Click on Keynote while on the Settings page in your screenshot, and then select Show in Finder in the bottom left. When the Finder is opened with Keynote highlighted, right-click on it and select Show Package Contents. Then, a new Finder window with the title "Keynote" will be opened. Select each folder in that window and press Command+I and see which one of these directories takes up the most space. If necessary, delve further into these directories individually. This may help you better understand the reason why Keynote seems to be taking up so much space.

Comment: Thank you both. I will look at DaisyDisk and also check out the Show Package Contents to see what I can find.

Comment: @TheBiker If you find out anything new and noteworthy, update your post to include it. If you find a solution, consider answering your question yourself so that others might benefit from your experience.

Comment: Please edit in the versions of both macOS and Keynote.